# Eclipse CDT indexing not working to find declarations within the project

Tags: eclipse, indexing, eclipse-cdt, include-path

I have installed Eclipse & CDT plugin on newly installed Ubuntu. The indexing is set to "Fast indexing" which is recommended ("Full Indexing" seems to have marginal difference).

At so many places, if I press `'F3'` ('show declaration') on any `class` name or include file name, the cursor remains stand still and it doesn't lead to the declaration. However, it works for standard files and symbols like, `stdio.h`, `std::vector` and so on.

For example, I have 2 files,

```
/home/myself/Workspace/Project/X/Y/include/file.h
/home/myself/Workspace/Project/X/src/file.cpp
```

I am not able to see any declaration of any `class` or variables displayed in `file.cpp` which are residing inside `file.h`. Even pressing `'F3'` on `#include"file.h"`, I am not able to go to `file.h`.

Eclipse Workspace is created at `Workspace` folder the C++ project is created at `Project` folder. To store the include path, I have followed this procedure in Eclipse:

**Project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Library and Paths -> Add "/Project/X/Y/include/file.h"** (used 'Workspace' and 'FileSystem' tabs both)

But still no luck. I have done enough searching on internet and SO, but couldn't find anything useful. Note that, I am using eclipse only for code browsing and not for building the code as of now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, got it working. Actually whatever *include paths* I have included in `Paths and Symbols` are redundant and they make no difference as everything under `Workspace/Project` will be indexed.

The solution is very weird and it's related to **scalability**, which I came to know from [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/642425/). In Eclipse go to,

> **Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Scalability -> "Enable scalability mode when ..."**

Set a huge number such as `500000` and press "OK". The problem was solved! For my case the actual set value was `5000` and the source file I was seeing was of `16k+` lines.

Comment: It is a bad sign when you have a C++ file that big.
Try refactoring a little just to help your sanity.

Comment: @Captain Lepton: or it's simply a sign you are using SWIG wrappers (or otherwise auto-generated code), or hardware device driver headers, or `sqlite.h`, or ... you get the point. It's not a bad sign _per se_.

Comment: I have worked with auto generated files including SWIG and various home grown systems for many years and wrote device drivers at my last job. None of these *have* to create monolithic files that cannot be factored out into more manageable logical units